# localhost prints .php file instead of executing it

Tags: php, macos, apache, localhost

I am running macOS 12.2.1 and I have installed php via `brew install php@7.4`. I have also added the following to my `http.conf`:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

But instead of executing my index.php, the browser just prints its code `<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>`

Now, I know that I'm supposed to add `LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so` to my `httpd.conf` as well, but if I do, I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I have noticed that all the other LoadModules point to a path `libexec/apache2/`.

Is my path incorrect? The file `/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so` does exist though... And I cannot find the directory `/libexec/apache2/` on my system..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was missing Code signing, I followed this guide and after a lot of trial and error now it works:
https://www.simplified.guide/macos/keychain-ca-code-signing-create

People who work at Apple are horrible people.